# A Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbf{F}$ and let $\beta = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$. Let $Q$ be an invertible matrix with entries from $\mathbf{F}$. Define
$$x^{'}_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Q_{ij}x_i\ \operatorname{for}\ 1\leq,i,j,\leq n\tag{1}$$
and set $\beta' = \{x_1^{'},x_2^{'},...,x_n^{'}\}$, then $\beta'$ is a basis for $V$.

**Proof.** Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n\in\mathbf{F}$ and assume that the  following is true.
$$0 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_jx^{'}_j\tag{2}$$ 
substituting $(1)$ in $(2)$ we have 
$$0 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_j\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Q_{ij}x_i\right)
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_jQ_{i,j}\right)x_j\tag{3}$$.

We may encapsulate our findings thus far by stating that

$$QA = 0\tag{4}$$
where $A = \begin{pmatrix}A_1\\A_2\\.\\.\\.\\A_n\end{pmatrix}$

Since the Matrix $Q$ is invertible it follows that 
$$A = Q^{-1}0 = 0\tag{5}$$

consequently $\forall j\in\{1,2,3...,n\}(A_j = 0)$ indicating that $\beta'$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, all you've shown explicitly is that the set you're interested in is linearly independent. You need a short remark explaining why the set is not just linearly independent but a basis. (There are several such remarks you could make, and you may think it's obvious, but better to be explicit.)

Comment: will it be sufficient to mention the fact that the length of $\beta'$ is $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.